# Trying create a translator based on a preset alphabet

Tags: javascript, html, translators

Ok, after looking at several different things, I'm unsure how to proceed with trying to create a very simple translator.

The translator will use an alphabet that I define for user input to pass through and convert. It's almost like a text to binary format, except I'm defining what stands for each letter.

For example: a = z, b = t, c = f, (etc).

For this I'm not sure if I should make an object and use hasOwnProperty

Like this: [Example](https://medium.com/@TimSeverien/substitution-cipher-in-javascript-d530eb2d923d#.j0w0sgln4)

or if I should just make an array and use a for loop.

If anyone could advise on the best course, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Either approach you presented could work. What is you main concerns (efficiency, simplicity, ...)?

Comment: You could use an Object with properties of the alphabet, with corresponding values being the letters you wish to convert to. You could then return the value of the property equal to your input.

Comment: Efficiency. I'm wanting to use it within an html page.

Comment: Don't bog yourself down with finding the most "efficient" solution before you even begin. Make it work. And after that, if it's slow, make it faster. Doing it in any other order is a waste of time.